# Google Search Map

Tags: javascript, html, maps

Something has crossed my mind recently and I can't seem to really find an answer .. I have tried few times and without success.

How do you get a google search box with places and locations without having the map on the same page.
You basically choose the place , then press search and it redirects to a map.

The part where I am stuck is that I just want the google search box from here , without the map ? Any ideas ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Here is another example :

[image]

To resume : Is it possible to have just the search box ? Then click a button and redirect to another page with the map.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it without the map, but I think you need to al least bound the SearchBox to an input and and then how you handle results is up to you, including redirecting to a different page.